# Django dynamic Search View based on filled GET request keys

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

please how is possible in Django to reach a view, which will be filtering based on filled keys from GET request?

I am using only one search view, but two forms:

[image: form1 and form2]

I am taking these requests:

```
q = request.GET.get('q') # this is for VIN and LOT number (two columns in Model/DB)
make = request.GET.get('make')
model = request.GET.get('model')
year_from = request.GET.get('year_from')
year_to = request.GET.get('year_from')
```

There are no required fields/requests, so it should work dynamically. If the user fills "q" - it will filter out by VIN or LOT number.
If the user will fill Make and Year, it will filter out by make and to year...

How is possible to do this, some better way, than **if , elif, elif, elif, ...** Is there any proper way, please?

This is my solution, but I really dont like it, it is not professional and I don't know, how to find a better solution

```
def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None


def search_filer(request):
    qs = Vehicle.objects.all()

    # VIN and Lot number
    q = request.GET.get('q')

    make = request.GET.get('make')
    model = request.GET.get('model')
    year_from = request.GET.get('year_from')
    year_to = request.GET.get('year_from')

    if is_valid_queryparam(q):
        qs = qs.filter(Q(vin__icontains=q) | Q(lot_number__icontains=q))

    elif is_valid_queryparam(make):
        qs = qs.filter(make__name__exact=make)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(model):
        qs = qs.filter(model__name__exact=model)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(year_from):
        qs = qs.filter(year__gte=year_from)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(year_to):
        qs = qs.filter(year__lte=year_to)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(make) and is_valid_queryparam(model):
        qs = qs.filter(make__name__exact=make)\
               .filter(model__name__exact=model)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(make) and is_valid_queryparam(model) and is_valid_queryparam(year_from):
        qs = qs.filter(make__name__exact=make)\
               .filter(model__name__exact=model)\
               .filter(year__gte=year_from)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(make) and is_valid_queryparam(model)\
            and is_valid_queryparam(year_from) and is_valid_queryparam(year_to):
        qs = qs.filter(make__name__exact=make)\
               .filter(model__name__exact=model)\
               .filter(year__gte=year_from)\
               .filter(year__lte=year_to)
        
        ...
        ...
        ...

    return qs


def search_view(request):
    qs = search_filer(request)

    # Year field for search form
    today = datetime.now()

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'years_from': reversed(range(1920, today.year + 1)),
        'years_to': reversed(range(1920, today.year + 1))
    }

    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

Thank you for any advice!

---

And also I don know, why context is not reusable, as you can see, I have created two variables **years_from** and **years_to** because I am looping through them in the template:

```
<option value>From ...</option>
{% for y in years_from %}
    <option value="{{ y }}">{{ y }}</option>
{% endfor %}

<option value>To ...</option>
{% for y in years_to %}
    <option value="{{ y }}">{{ y }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

When I tried to create only a one-year variable and loop through in template, it was working. But when I created another loop with the same variable, no values were shown. So I have created exact same variable and looped.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out, how to solve that. It is really not professional, but it does the desired work. I will be glad for any advice or hints, to make my code better. If someone will be trying something like me, here is my solution:

```
def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None


def is_valid_name(name):
    return name == 'make' or name == 'model' or name == 'year_from' or name == 'year_to'


def get_filter(key):
    if key == 'make':
        return 'make__name__exact'
    if key == 'model':
        return 'model__name__exact'
    if key == 'year_from':
        return 'year__gte'
    if key == 'year_to':
        return'year__lte'


def search_view(request):
    queryset = None
    valid_params = False

    # VIN and LOT number
    q = request.GET.get('q')

    if is_valid_queryparam(q):
        queryset = Vehicle.objects.filter(Q(vin__icontains=q) | Q(lot_number__icontains=q))
    else:
        request_filter = {}
        q_list = Q()
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            if is_valid_name(key) and is_valid_queryparam(value):
                valid_params = True
                request_filter[get_filter(key)] = value
        if valid_params:
            for k, v in request_filter.items():
                q_list.add(Q(**{k: v}), Q.AND)

            queryset = Vehicle.objects.filter(q_list)

    # Year field for search form
    today = datetime.now()
    years_from = reversed(range(1920, today.year + 1))
    years_to = reversed(range(1920, today.year + 1))

    context = {
        'queryset': queryset,
        'years_from': years_from,
        'years_to': years_to
    }
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```